# System of two equations with two unknowns - can't get rid of $xy$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

The system is:

$x^2 + 2y^2 + 3xy = 12$
$y^2 - 3y = 4$

I try to turn $x^2 + 2y^2 + 3xy$ into $(x + y)^2 + y^2 + xy$ , but it's a dead end from here. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Solve $12y^2-3y-4=0$ for $y$

Set those two values one by one in the first equation

Comment: How did you remove the 12 coefficient in front of $y^2$?

Comment: @darkradeon, Sorry I could not read the Ques properly, please find the edited version

Comment: The discrimanant is not an integer, are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @darkradeon, Values does not matter

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the second part $$12 y^2 - 3y = 4$$ it is just a quadratic equations the roots of which being $$y_{\pm}=\frac{1}{24} \left(3\pm\sqrt{201}\right)$$ Now, consider $x^2 + 2y^2 + 3xy = 4$ where $y$ is a known parameter and you get another quadratic in $x$ the roots of which being $$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(\pm\sqrt{y^2+16}-3 y\right)$$ Replace $y$ by its values and get the corresponding $x$'s.

This will give you four solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The system consists the two equations 
$x^2 + 2y^2 + 3xy = 12$ and (!) 
$y^2 - 3y = 4.$

From the second equation we get $y=-1, y=4.$  Then from the first equation we find $x.$